# Integral containing Associated Legendre Polynomials

Tags: definite-integrals, legendre-polynomials

I need to evaluated the following integral:

$\int_0^\pi \sin(x) \cos(x) P_l^m(\cos x) P_k^m(\cos x) \mathrm{d}x$

and I thought since a solution is known to a similar thing

$\int_0^\pi \sin(x) P_l^m(\cos x) P_k^m(\cos x) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{2(l+m)!}{(2l+1)(l-m)!}\delta_{l,k}$

maybe this is the case with an additional $\cos x$ as well.

Comment: What do you mean by $P_k^m(x)$? The $m$-th derivative of the Legendre polynomial $P_k(x)$?

Comment: Sorry, $P_k^m(x)$ are the associated Legendre Polynomials.

Comment: Ok. By the way, I think it would be nicer to include the definition $$P_\ell^{m}(x) = (-1)^m\ (1-x^2)^{m/2}\ \frac{d^m}{dx^m}\left(P_\ell(x)\right)$$ in your question to avoid counter-questions like mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$P_l^{m}(x) = (-1)^m\ (1-x^2)^{m/2}\ \frac{d^m}{dx^m}\left(P_l(x)\right)\tag{1}$$
the second integral equals:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)P_{l}^{m}(\sin x)P_{k}^{m}(\sin x)\,dx + \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)P_{l}^{m}(-\sin x)P_{k}^{m}(-\sin x)\,dx $$
or:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}P_{l}^{m}(x) P_{k}^{m}(x)\,dx + \int_{0}^{1}P_{l}^{m}(-x) P_{k}^{m}(-x)\,dx=\int_{-1}^{1}P_l^m(x)P_k^m(x)\,dx$$
and
$$ \int_{-1}^{1}P_l^m(x) P_k^m(x)\,dx = \frac{2(l+m)!}{(2l+1)(l-m)!}\delta_{k,l}\tag{2}$$
follows from the [orthogonality relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials) for the associated Legendre polynomials.

The first integral equals:
$$ \int_{-1}^{1}|x|\, P_{l}^{m}(x)\, P_{k}^{m}(x)\,dx\tag{3}$$
and it can be computed through [Gaunt's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials#Gaunt.27s_formula) once we expand $|x|$ in terms of Legendre polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer about using Gaunt's theorem won't hold unless some condition regarding the degrees are satisfied.